# Inside ListView multiple toggleButton is getting on ,on clicking one toggleButton

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an **ExpandableListView** and inside each Parent Row .

I am having a ToggleButton ,when I switch on one toggle button ,on scrolling below i am getting multiple toggleButton switched on. Why is this happening, I am getting groupPosition everything correctly in my log?

**here is my code :**

```
public class WifiAPListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private WifiAPListActivity context;
    public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiStatus checkWifiStatus;
    public ToggleButton togglebtn;
    int pos;
    Holder holder;
    int previousPosition = -1;
    private static final int CHILD_COUNT = 1;

    public WifiAPListAdapter(WifiAPListActivity context,
            ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> result) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = result;
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        checkWifiStatus = new WifiStatus(context);

    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return groups.get(groupPosition);

    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        previousPosition = groupPosition;
        ExpandListGroup child = (ExpandListGroup) getChild(groupPosition,
                groupPosition);
        // Log.i("", "getChildView: "+childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_item, null);
            holder.label_ssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_ssid);
            holder.tv_ssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvssid);
            holder.label_bssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_bssid);
            holder.tv_bssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvbssid);
            holder.label_capabilities = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.label_capabilities);
            holder.tv_capabilities = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvcapabilities);
            holder.label_signalStrength = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.label_signalstrength);
            holder.tv_signalStrength = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvsignalstrength);
            holder.wifi_signalimg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.signal);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();

        }

        // *********************setting data to the child list**************

        holder.tv_ssid.setText(child.getSSID());
        holder.tv_bssid.setText(child.getBSSID());
        holder.tv_capabilities.setText(child.getCapabilities());
        holder.tv_signalStrength.setText(child.getData());

        Bitmap bitmap = setSignalImage(Integer.parseInt(child.getData()));
        holder.wifi_signalimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return view;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.i("", "getChildrenCount: " + groupPosition);

        return CHILD_COUNT;

    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        Log.i("", "getGroupCount: " + groups.size());
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.i("", "getGroupView: " + groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_parent_items, null);

            holder.tv_ssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ssid);
            holder.tv_bssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bssid);
            holder.btn_toggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.togBtn);

            // holder.btn_toggle.setTag(groups.get(groupPosition).getBSSID());

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }
        // holder.btn_toggle.setTag(groups.get(groupPosition).getBSSID());
        holder.tv_ssid.setText(groups.get(groupPosition).getSSID());
        holder.tv_bssid.setText(groups.get(groupPosition).getBSSID());

        return view;
    }

    public void toggle(View v) {
        if (holder.btn_toggle.isChecked()) {
        }
        Log.i("", "toggle");
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }
```

can any body tell a good method to avoid this problem without removing holder because if i would have n number of items then its not a good idea to draw view every time we should use holder.

Answer (score 0):

remove holder and close if loop for inflate like how i am closed also use logic for toggle inside getGroupView .because every time u scroll the listview the getGroupView get called so every time it this method has to check the condition.

```
 private WifiAPListActivity context;
    public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiStatus checkWifiStatus;
    public ToggleButton togglebtn;
    int pos;
    Holder holder;
    int previousPosition = -1;
    private static final int CHILD_COUNT = 1;

    public WifiAPListAdapter(WifiAPListActivity context,
            ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> result) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = result;
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        checkWifiStatus = new WifiStatus(context);

    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return groups.get(groupPosition);

    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        previousPosition = groupPosition;
        ExpandListGroup child = (ExpandListGroup) getChild(groupPosition,
                groupPosition);
        // Log.i("", "getChildView: "+childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_item, null);
            }
           label_ssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_ssid);
           tv_ssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvssid);
            label_bssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_bssid);
            tv_bssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvbssid);
            label_capabilities = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.label_capabilities);
            tv_capabilities = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvcapabilities);
            label_signalStrength = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.label_signalstrength);
            tv_signalStrength = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvsignalstrength);
            wifi_signalimg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.signal);



        // *********************setting data to the child list**************

        tv_ssid.setText(child.getSSID());
        tv_bssid.setText(child.getBSSID());
        tv_capabilities.setText(child.getCapabilities());
        tv_signalStrength.setText(child.getData());

        Bitmap bitmap = setSignalImage(Integer.parseInt(child.getData()));
        wifi_signalimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return view;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.i("", "getChildrenCount: " + groupPosition);

        return CHILD_COUNT;

    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        Log.i("", "getGroupCount: " + groups.size());
        return groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.i("", "getGroupView: " + groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_parent_items, null);
      }

            tv_ssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ssid);
            tv_bssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bssid);
            btn_toggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.togBtn);

            // holder.btn_toggle.setTag(groups.get(groupPosition).getBSSID());



        // holder.btn_toggle.setTag(groups.get(groupPosition).getBSSID());
        tv_ssid.setText(groups.get(groupPosition).getSSID());
        tv_bssid.setText(groups.get(groupPosition).getBSSID());

        return view;
    }

    public void toggle(View v) {
        if (btn_toggle.isChecked()) {
        }
        Log.i("", "toggle");
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: it is working but now on scrolling the state on is not getting saved it again became off.

Comment: is that toggle button dynamic or static.ie will that list keep on changes

Comment: it is dynamic,toggleButton is an item of parent not the child so why should i check inside getChildView ,I did't get you will you please explain in detail ?

Comment: i have one logic for u .u should create an hashmap with size of ur list and put false for all values. then while u press the toggle get the position and make the hashmap of that position true.in getGroupView check if hashmap of that position true then toggle.check else dot check

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of mechanism of Recycling of Views. I had written a [blog post](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) for the same taking into consideration ListView.

If you are not aware about recycling of views then probably you must read [this blog](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) to get exact idea about how recycling of view works!